# Can a web.config key value pair be used as a compile time constant in asp.net c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-config

I am trying to do this below, is there a way to do this or are web.configs only available at run-time, because I am getting a red line error saying must be compile time constant?

AppSettings:

```
  <add key="MyString" value="TheValueOfTheString"/>
```

Code:

```
   public const string MyString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyString"];
```

Comment: why dont you create static variable???

Comment: Its based on the fact that I need to use a const value for LogonAuthorize Attribute tag, in the mvc application.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

the problem is the use of const. const means the value is hard coded at design time.

```
const string MyString = "the text...";
```

an appsettings value is not known until runtime so it's not a constant value. instead you can use a static readonly value

```
static readonly MyString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyString"];
```

the difference is how the value is interpereted at compile time. when a constant is used the actual value is referenced, not the variable `MyString`. a `static readonly` value is compiled as the variable.

Comment: `readonly` will prevent the value from changing. similar to a `constant`.

Comment: so basically it's not possible to use a const string with the key value pair, but this is the closest answer.

Comment: correct. a KVP, or any other referenced value is just that, a reference, not a constant.